# QPushButton is not clicked on the first click

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qpushbutton

I have Qt 5.6 and I'm using the pressed signal of a button witch then shows a dialog. unfortunately the button of dialog is not clicked in the first time but the second click is working perfectly.
you can test this situation by showing a `QMessageBox::information` in a `on_someButton_pressed` slot.

Comment: What signal do you connect to - [clicked](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) or [pressed](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#pressed) ?

Comment: as I mentioned in the question its **pressed** signal.

Comment: Worked for me just as expected, dialog opening on pressing mouse button down... And all I did was to create a widget project, add a push button in designer, then "Go to slot...": `void MainWindow::on_pushButton_pressed() {     QMessageBox::information(this, "INFO", "Text...", QMessageBox::Ok); }`

Comment: Please post your code so we can determine if there are issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can't reproduce: works for me. And *you* should have written this test case. It's almost less words to code it up than to describe the problem.

```
#include <QtWidgets>
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QPushButton button{"Press me"};
   button.setMinimumSize(300, 150);
   button.setFont(QFont{"Helvetica", 20});
   QObject::connect(&button, &QPushButton::pressed, [&]{
       QMessageBox::information(&button, "Yes!", "You pressed me.");
   });
   button.show();
   app.exec();
}
```

As an aside, you should be using the `clicked()` signal, not the `pressed()` signal. Usability suffers if you use the latter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But maybe I didn't explain the situation well. The problem is not the push button 'button' itself but the push button in the dialog. For example the OK button in the 'QMesageBox'. You should click OK button twice to close the information dialog. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Have you run the test case above? It works just fine!

Comment: Sorry but I don't have any problem with it in Windows. But in beagle bone black and a touch screen I have this issue. Qt version 5.6, tool chain linaro 4.9, cross compiling from Ubuntu 16.04. I think the event is not handled in Qt event handler the first time.

Comment: You assume that the platform delivers the event to Qt to begin with. I'd treat it as an unsubstantiated assumption unless you have hard proof otherwise (i.e. you catch the event as it's delivered to Qt's native event handler, and then fail to trace it to the widget).